# Jade expression to render image from url sends another request to the server

Tags: angularjs, pug

I have a jade file, where I parse the user data and construct the page. There is a place in this file where I loop through the users' images and render them to the page:

```
.picture-item(ng-repeat='m in userProfile.media')
  img.picture(src='{{m.mediaUrl}}')
```

But the problem is, even though this line of code shows the image on the page, it send another request to server like below:

`http://localhost:3000/%7B%7Bm.mediaUrl%7D%7D`

This happens on: `http://localhost:3000/profile` page. If I go to a user's profile, let's say: `http://localhost:3000/profile/some_username`, then the code above sends a request like:

```
http://localhost:3000/profile/%7B%7Bm.mediaUrl%7D%7D
```

`m.mediaUrl` are user's instagram image urls.

What could be the problem here? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a known issue with AngularJS client side late binding.

You can use another attribute for the `img` tag instead:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

```
   .picture-item(ng-repeat='m in userProfile.media')
     img.picture(ngSrc='{{m.mediaUrl}}')
```

Comment: This solved the issue, but lemme ask you another one: what about `.picture(style="background-image: url({m.mediaUrl})")`? This does the exact same thing. I changed it to `img.picture(ng-src="{{m.mediaUrl}}")` and it works but got curious about what about the css structured in a way that we cannot change `background-image` to `ng-src`? what should I do then?